# Print(Key-Value + Definition each)

Tags: python, printing

What this program will do is read user input to make a dictionary. to make it basic i have made it as names and colors. I want to be able to take the info from the dictionary and then print it just so i know the first part is doing before i go on to the next step.

```
colourdef = {}

line = input('Name and colour: ')
while line:
  name, colour = line.split()
  colourdef[name] = colour
  line = input('Name and number: ')

for each in range(len(colourdef)):
  print(name, colour(each))
```

i know that it is the last line that's wrong i can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: You don't need to use a for loop, you may simply print the `dict` directly as: `print(colourdef)`

Comment: Hmm...looks like your `while` loop never stop, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Dict is indexed by keys ( the 'name' string in your case ), not number indexes as array.

```
 for name,colour in colourdef.items():
      print name,colour
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little hacky but gets the job done.

```
colourdef = {}
while True:
  try :
    _ = raw_input('Name and colour:')
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    break
  name, colour = _.split()
  colourdef[name] = colour

print colourdef
```